# What is the easiest way to export a Docker container to VM

Tags: docker, production-environment

I have Hbase docker container running in dev server. What is the best way to export it to production VM with all data inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the command `docker commit` you can create a image from a container, then put the image on your resgistry, and in Production use the command `docker run` to run the container with the new image. The new image will have all data inside.

**Example:**

1. On dev, get the id of your by `docker ps`

   ```
   docker ps
   CONTAINER ID      IMAGE        COMMAND            CREATED        STATUS              PORTS                   NAMES
   ba8a9e9ecd1b      Hbase/ex1    "/sbin/my_init"    12 days ago    Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:80, 0.0.0.0:80  dev-c
   ```
2. Create a new image from the container

   ```
   docker commit ba8a9e9ecd1b repo/new-image
   ```
3. Push you new image to registry

   ```
   docker push repo/new-image
   ```
4. Run the container in Production

   ```
   docker run -itd repo/new-image
   ```